# how to use nested iteration in lightning and what is the alternative of apex:variable in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a list of custom class objects. I am using aura:iteration to iterate the list. Now I want to show one of the variable of the class object which in itself is object.
For example in Salesforce Classic

```
<apex:repeat value="{!RequiredStoreActivities}" var="activity">
    <apex:variable value="{!activity.StoreActivityCategory}" var="activityCategory" />
    <div >
        <span ></span>
        <apex:outputText value="{!activityCategory.Store_Activity_Category__c}" />
    </div>

    <div >
        <ul >
            <apex:repeat value="{!activity.StoreActivities}" var="storeActivity">
                <li>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!storeActivity.Name}" />
                </li>
            </apex:repeat>
        </ul>
    </div>                    
</apex:repeat>
```

Where RequiredStoreActivities is a class

```
public class RequiredStoreActivity{

  public final Store_Visit_Activity_Category__c StoreActivityCategory {get; private set;}
  public List<Store_Activity__c> StoreActivities {get; set;}
}
```

I have to implement the same in lightning. Can somebody help me in it
till now I am able to code the below code

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.RequiredStoreActivity}" var="st">
    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.showActivity1}">
        <c:StoreActCategory storeActivityCategory="{!st.StoreActivityCategory}"/> 
    </aura:renderIf>
</aura:iteration>
```

Since we cannot use `apex:iteration` inside `apex:iteration`. I have passed the value to a component. But on the another component the value is getting undefined

Answer (score 3):

Just tried aura:iteration inside the aura:iteration and works great .Here is a sample that clearly shows no harm in using nested aura:iterations

```
<aura:component >

<aura:attribute name="arrvals" type="integer[]" default="1,2,3,4,5"/>    

   <aura:iteration var="num" items="{!v.arrvals}" aura:id="ipv" indexVar="index">
     <aura:iteration var="num1" items="{!v.arrvals}" aura:id="ip12" indexVar="index">
      {!num1}
   </aura:iteration>         
  </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

What you might be missing from my opinion is below

> Make sure All your inner varibales are annotated @Aura Enabled

The equivalent of apex:var in lightning is aura:attribute .You can declare aura:attribute to store and retrieve values from same as you do for apex:variable in Visualforce

Comment: Hi Mohith thanks for your reply. I tried using aura:attribute inside aura:iteration but it's giving me an error of invalid name. Whereas when placed it outside iteration it worked. But I need it inside aura: iteration. Can you please check and tell me the solution. It's very urgent

Comment: @Radhika Can you post all code you have so i can assist better ? The code that you have provided is not sufficient to put right answer .Share your apex and all lightning component code

Comment: I have mailed you on mohith.shrivastava@salesforcemvps.com. can you please check. Thanks